# Rebuke the violent damage from attack where damage is reduced

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, paladin, damage-reduction

Rebuke the violent says:

> Immediately after an attacker within 30 feet of you deals damage with an attack against a creature other than you, you can use your reaction to force the attacker to make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, **the attacker takes radiant damage equal to the damage it just dealt**.

There are several situations where the damage the attacker rolls and the hp taken off differ. Rage, interception, deflect missile and resistances to poison etc.

In the situation where a thug shoots the paladin's monk ally for 10 points of piercing damage with the monk's deflect missile reducing that to 0 points. Would rebuke the violent deal 10 or 0 points of damage?

I did find a similar [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/181524/how-much-damage-is-dealt-taken-when-that-damage-also-reduces-a-creature-to-0-hit) which instead looks at when a creature is taken to 0hp and the damage was actually taken rather than actively being deflected or absorbed by resistance - especially given that in some cases the damage could be reduced to 0.

Comment: [Is there a difference between "damage taken" and "damage dealt"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/182308) [Is the value of "damage dealt/taken" calculated after resistances?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162342) [Is the Undead Fortitude trait's DC based on damage dealt or damage taken?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164151) [How much damage is dealt/taken when that damage also reduces a creature to 0 hit points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181524) [What is damage you do vs. damage a creature takes? (and Dark One's Blessing)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176844)

Comment: Do any of those answer your question?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Kinda - I mean I think they're covering some of the same bases and the answer may lie somewhere in a combination of them. However reopening my question as a slightly different spin on the existing questions doesn't seem worth it for something that is already being argued both ways. Sounds like its just a DM's discretion sort of thing.

Comment: Yeah, I think that’s the right call. The list I gave isn’t even exhaustive, it’s all that would fit in one comment. I think we’ve pretty well established that situations like the one in your question are bound to cause confusion, and there isn’t a great answer. I don’t think we need to rehash it every time we find a similar interaction.